# How can nonscalar aliases be implemented in LLVM IR?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

My goal is to be able to create an array alias, e.g. for variables `a` and `b` located in non-contiguous memory, I can create a variable `c` that can be dereferenced such that `c[0]` is an alias for `a` and `c[1]` is an alias for `b`.  Right now I am using an LLVM ConstantArray initializer containing global aliases to the desired variables, which results in the following IR:

```
@C = alias i16, i16* @A
@C.1 = alias i16, i16* @B
```

Is this the proper way to implement the desired behavior?  I'm having trouble creating importing this variable into C (via extern) in a way that behaves as described above.

Comment: Arrays of references are illegal.

Comment: Is the behavior I'm describing then impossible to implement?

Comment: You can have an array of std::reference_wrapper.